# Mock object created in the constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a constructor for `EdmService` that creates an object `EdmApiClient` in the constructor

```
public EdmService(IOptions<EdmApiClientOptions> apiOptions, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    Check.ArgumentIsNotNull(apiOptions, nameof(apiOptions));
    Check.ArgumentIsNotNull(httpClientFactory, nameof(httpClientFactory));
    _client = new EdmApiClient(apiOptions.Value.Hostname, httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(EdmApiClient)));
}
```

This `_client` is used in the method that I want to test. But how to mock it?

Comment: if your Sut creates a depency itself, there's no way to mock it. You'd need to override your SuT's constructor and prevent the original from being executed. That's the point of Dependency Injection: don't make your SuT create its dependencies, but inject them from the outside.

Comment: Hm, so the only chance is to mock `stub` http client factory that would do fake call inside `edmClient`?

Comment: If you don't want to change your SuT to inject the depency, then yes, you can only fake the factory.

Comment: But I don't think I can change `_client` in any shape or form? I need to create this object after all

Comment: You might exchange the object at _client with a mock via reflection after the constructor executed. But still its fighting against code that isn't written for testability but should. If its just used this way presumably EdmApiClient is itself also not written to be easily mockable.

Comment: the question is not about *if* you need to create the client, but *where*. You could easily introduce a parameter to the constructor of type `EdmApiClient` and create that object **outside** your method.

Comment: I suggest you read up on Dependency Inversion amd Dependency Injection. This is more than an answer can reasonably encompass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mock it if the service creates a new instance. You must change your service to accept all its dependencies via the constructor:

```
public EdmService(IOptions<EdmApiClientOptions> apiOptions, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, EdmApiClient client)
{
    Check.ArgumentIsNotNull(apiOptions, nameof(apiOptions));
    Check.ArgumentIsNotNull(httpClientFactory, nameof(httpClientFactory));
    _client = client;
}

public static void Main() {
    var svc = new EdmService(
        apiOptions,
        httpClientFactory,
        new EdmApiClient(
            apiOptions.Value.Hostname,
            httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(EdmApiClient)));
}
```

If passing the client is not an option, consider passing a factory instead.

```
public EdmService(IOptions<EdmApiClientOptions> apiOptions, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, Func<String, IHttpClient, EdmApiClient> clientFactory)
{
    Check.ArgumentIsNotNull(apiOptions, nameof(apiOptions));
    Check.ArgumentIsNotNull(httpClientFactory, nameof(httpClientFactory));
    _client = client(apiOptions.Value.Hostname, httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(EdmApiClient)));
}

public static void Main() {
    var svc = new EdmService(
        apiOptions,
        httpClientFactory,
        (hostname, client) => new EdmApiClient(hostname, client));
}
```

Or use the real `EdmApiClient`, but have your `httpClientFactory` return a test double.